# Message breakes Xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap

I have an opredefined xml in which, I sign the header and get the **correct** xml.
After that, an object of the Message class is created, in which the xml is formatted (new lines `\r \n` are added). Accordingly, the signature format is broken.

```
var signedXml = SignHeader(xml);
            
var xmlReaderAll = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(signedXml));

request = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReaderAll, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
```